# Program crashes when I try to get the IAudioClient for a channel

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am using Discord.Net Api to make a bot the connects to a discord server and I want to bot to play music and audio.
I can make the bot join a channel and it works great, but when I try to get the `IAudioClient` for the channel(from the `IAudioClient` I can get the audio output stream so I can write the music to it and that's what transfers the music) , I get an exception.
This is my code for joining the channel and then getting the `IAudioClient` for the channel:

```
    [Command("join")]
    public async Task JoinChannel(IVoiceChannel channel = null)
    {
        channel = channel ?? (callingUser as IGuildUser)?.VoiceChannel;
        if(channel == null)
        {
            await callingMsg.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You must be in a voice channel.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Channel: " + channel.Name + " - " + channel.Id);
        try
        {
            audioClient = await channel.ConnectAsync(); //crashes here
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

I don't know if it makes the problem here, but I installed only the "ffmpeg" for the audio transmitting, but so far I don't see any problems with that, only with getting the audio channel. I used this tutorial: https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/voice/sending-voice.html
but on the top of the tutorial you can see a caption which says that the tutorial is out of date..

the exception I get is `The operation has timed out`.

> 21:39:18 Discord     Discord.Net v1.0.1 (API v6)
>   21:39:19 Gateway     Connecting
>   21:39:20 Gateway     Connected
>   21:39:20 Gateway     Ready
>   Channel: תודה תודה תודה תודה תודה - 334069917047455747
>   21:39:29 Gateway     A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task.
>      at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.d__160.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.d__160.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Discord.WebSocket.SocketVoiceChannel.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at ruin_counter.Program.d__9.MoveNext()

Comment: Please tell us what exception you got and if possible include the stack trace.

Comment: @hoodaticus Edited. Check it out.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to be much help here.  I would try doing a non-async connect at the failing line to see if it works.  The timeout makes it seem like you are being ignored on the server-side for some reason.

Comment: @hoodaticus there isn't any synchronous way to do that using this api, only async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `await channel.ConnectAsync()` can take some time until it returns a value, so I just noticed that I can write another method inside the brackets and that other method with get the needed `IAudioClient` like that:
`audioClient = await channel.ConnectAsync(SendAsync);`

```
        private void SendAsync(IAudioClient audioClient)
    {
        var ffmpeg = CreateStream("tune.mp3");
        var output = ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
        var discord = audioClient.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed);
        output.CopyToAsync(discord);
        discord.FlushAsync();        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your command is timing out, it's because 'async' isn't exactly async. You need to set the RunMode of your command to Async

`[Command("name",RunMode = RunMode.Async)]`

Comment: it didn't help but I found a way to fix that crash.